# Adding columns to view-based NSTableView programmatically

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I currently have a cell-based NSTableView where I need to add columns and bind them to my model. The text size for the columns is System-Small and everything works great because I can programmatically set the properties of the dataCell when I create the column.

With a view-based table and no dataCell, how can I make sure during the column creation that the text cell is the right size, etc? There does not seem to be a way to store a template column in the nib and load it multiple times (each time changing the identifier), before adding it to the table.

In switching to a view-based NSTableView, I understand that I can't bind a whole column on creation like I can with cell-based tables, but instead have to do it during:

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
```

I can bind like this, but just need a way to pre-configure the appearance and layout of a column as I can't figure out how to even find the views within a new column as they don't have any identifiers like they would if they came from some sort of template.

Comment: In view-based tables, the cell view takes care of its own layout, sizing, etc. through constraints and similar mechanisms. As far as finding the views, you're going to be providing them through the delegate (unless you're reusing views pre-defined in the nib, in which case they'll work exactly like your other columns).

Comment: I just need to create a new column with a fairly generic text view. Where do I define this view in the nib since the column does not exist in the nib at all? I need to be able to give the text view basic properties like text style.

Comment: If your view isn't in the nib (anywhere) then you must provide it in your `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` delegate method. You can create a new `NSTableCellView` and populate it with whatever content you want, with bindings, and constraints to define its layout. You should also assign it a column identifier and include a call to `-makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` to recycle them.